# LC3 LEA instruction and the value stored

Tags: assembly, load, cpu-registers, lc3

I am confused by this question: What is the value stored in register 0 after instruction `“LEA R0,A"` is executed? How come the answer is x370C ? I reckon it is supposed to load the address of A into R0? If so how do we know the address?  Can someone please help? Many thanks!

```
.ORIG X3700
 LEA R0, A
 LDI R2, C LDR R3, R0, 2 
 AND R1, R1, #0 
 IN
 ST R0, D 
 JSR  F 
 HALT
F LD  R1, B
 ADD R1, R1, #1
 BRp F 
 RET

 A .FILL X1234
 B .FILL X370B
 C .FILL X370C
 D .BLKW 2
 E .STRINGZ "ABCD"
 G .FILL X1234
 .END
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The origin of the code is `x3700`, and you have 12 instructions, so the address of `A` will be `x3700 + x0C = x370C`. As you guessed, `LEA R0,A` loads the address of `A` into `R0`, so `R0` will contain `x370C` after that first instruction has been executed.

```
        .ORIG X3700
3700     LEA R0, A
3701     LDI R2, C
3702     LDR R3, R0, 2 
         ...
370b     RET

370c     A .FILL X1234
         ...
```

Comment: No problem - I've rolled back your edit for you to keep this question and answer useful. Feel free to start a new question if you're still having problems.

Comment: Can you take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30007738/how-does-lea-instruction-store-address-of-a      It's directly based off this question